# Is halting problem for /// solvable assuming programs that maches the regex "^/[ab]*/[ab]*/[ab]*$"?

Tags: halting-problem

[///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////) is an esoteric language, and I thought of posting a code-golf problem related to it.

A /// program of the  form `/p/q/r` where p, q, and r are strings that do not contain `/` or `\` does:

1. If the string p is a substring of r, go to step 2; otherwise step 5.
2. Replace the leftmost occurrence of p in r with q.
3. Let the result of step 2 be the new r.
4. Go to step 1.
5. Output r and halt.

In step 1, an empty string shall be a substring of any strings.

For simplicity I am thinking each of p, q, r consisting of zero or more `a`'s and `b`'s.

At first I thought the following algorithm would work:

1. Returns no if p is both a substring of q and r; otherwise yes.

But that was wrong; `/ab/bbaa/abb` can be one of the exceptions, as "ab" does not appear in "bbaa" but in "abb".

I am suspecting it's possibly impossible to make an algorithm to solve this problem. Is it solvable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [Math Overflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/181918), the answer is not known as of 2014.

It seems your problem can be restated to asking if the termination of one-rule [string-rewriting systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-Thue_system) is decidable. A rule of a string-rewriting system is a substitution like the one you gave with $ab\to bbaa$.

Even though the Math Overflow answer doesn't distinguish between alphabet size, which in your case is only 2 consisting only of $\{a,b\}$, you can convert a SRS with a larger alphabet into one with only 2 letters, thus making their termination problems equivalent. Basically, give each letter a unique index $n$, then replace it with $ab^na$ in both the input string as well as the rules. So for example $cad→addc$ can be encoded as $abbbaabaabbbba→abaabbbbaabbbbaabbba$.

Comment: The fastest-growing terminating such rule I could find so far was $ab→bba$ on the input $a^nb$, which grows exponentially in $n$.